# win32client dispatch fails in python while win32::ole new runs successfully in perl for a com dll

Tags: python, perl, com, win32com, win32ole

I have a com dll implemented in C# and is registered via regasm.
When I try to get a handle to this dll in python via

```
handle = win32com.client.Dispatch('{EC456B4B-5AC4-46E8-99E8-54C193C316BC}')
```

or

```
handle = win32com.client.Dispatch('MyCOMdll')
```

it fails with an error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)

while this works in the perl script where I use

```
my $handle = Win32::OLE->new('MyCOMdll');
```

or

```
my $handle = Win32::OLE->new('{EC456B4B-5AC4-46E8-99E8-54C193C316BC}');
```

Meanwhile win32com.client.Dispatch is working good for the COM exe objects.

Is the way I am using the win32.comclient for COM dlls correct ?

---

[update 01]

perl code which is working

```
use Win32::OLE;
my $handle = Win32::OLE->new('MyCOMdll');
# my $handle = Win32::OLE->new('{EC456B4B-5AC4-46E8-99E8-54C193C316BC}');
my $result = Win32::OLE->LastError();
if ($result != 0)
{
    print("OLE Error: ",$result,"/n");
    die "";
}
else
{
    print("OLE Success!!/n");
}
exit 0;
```

Python code which works only for COM exe and not for COM dlls

```
import win32com.client

try:
    handle = win32com.client.Dispatch('MyCOMdll')
    # handle = win32com.client.Dispatch('{EC456B4B-5AC4-46E8-99E8-54C193C316BC}')
except Exception as ex:
    handle = None
    print(ex)
```

Comment: Smells like a 32/64 bit issue. Make sure your client is of the same bitness as the COM dll

Comment: @SimonMourier:  2.7.12 [MSC v.1500 **32 bit** (Intel)] is the python version,  **v5.14.4 MSWin32-x86-multi-thread** is the perl version and the COM dll is built for **x86** target in visual studio

Comment: @SimonMourier: Looks like the 32 bit and 64 bit issue. I removed the previous registrations and did re registration and tried with 32 bit python, now the error is different (OLE error 0x80131534: Guess some issue with the dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

It was a 32 bit/ 64 bit problem. After using a 32 bit python version, the issue was resolved.